# Grails integration test - Writing test to check, how many times a function is called in service class

Tags: grails

I have a service method which in-turn calls another method from it, mutiple times.

> def methodA(){
>
> ....
>     methodB()
>     ....
>
> }

Is there a way to write an integration test, which could test the number of times the "methodB()" is called?

It can be done using unit test, but can it be done in integration?

Comment: yes. i am using spock

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular JUnit 3 test, but the approach would work fine in a Spock test.

You can use the `&.` operator to get a reference to a method and call the method via the reference, so I would do that and then replace the method in the metaclass with a closure that increments a counter and then calls the real method using the saved reference.

```
class FooServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    def fooService

    void testCountMethodB() {

        def methodB = fooService.&methodB

        int count = 0
        fooService.metaClass.methodB = { ->
            count++
            methodB()
        }

        fooService.methodA()
        assert count == 5 // or whatever number you expect
    }
}
```

If `methodB` has arguments, be sure to register a closure with the same signature, e.g.

```
fooService.metaClass.methodB = { int bar, String wahoo ->
   count++
   methodB(bar, wahoo)
}
```